# What does `#define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n` do here?

Tags: c, macros

I saw following macro [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

```
static const char LogTable256[256] = 
{
#define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n
    -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
    LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};
```

What does `#define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n` do here?

Comment: replaces actual value of passed `n` 16 times

Comment: Have you just called it somewhere and inspect the outcome?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question. Please refer to your favorite book or tutorial instead.

Comment: try `gcc -E yoursource.c` and see what comes out.

Comment: You can have your compiler expand macros for you. Edit: what jean said 7 seconds before me :)

Comment: Please note that negative numbers and `char` type should never be mixed, because `char` has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you have to do is to put that in a file ( say `t.c` )

> t.c

```
static const char LogTable256[256] =
{
#define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n
    -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
    LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};
```

and then gcc with -E switch

> ```
> gcc -E t.c
> ```

here is the output for convenience

```
# 1 "t.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "t.c"
static const char LogTable256[256] =
{

    -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If simply repeats its argument 16 times. See how it is used in the code at your link, immediately after its definition, to produce sequential repetitive values in the initializer of `LogTable256` array:

```
static const char LogTable256[256] = 
{
    -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
    LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};
```

No rocket science here. Just saves some typing, no more no less.